# Elastic Query for SQL like query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

want to search in elastic search, like we do in SQL query = (age = 25 and name = xyz).

This for a single field and single data.

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: i want to search in elastic search document like SQL query => age = 25 and name = xyz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its very much possible, just use below ES Mapping and query:

### Mapping

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "age" :{
                "type" : "integer"
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "number_of_replicas": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

### Index a doc

```
{
    "name": "xyz",
    "age" : 25
}
```

### Query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "xyz"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "age": 25
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer

```
POST _sql?format=txt {
"query":"SELECT age, name FROM collection WHERE age=25 AND name ='xyz'"
}
```

See also
https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch-sql